# Is it possible to install Worklight Studio offline?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am interested in installing Worklight Studio offline as a firewall rule prevents me from checking for required items for the install.

I am using the downloadable zip file, WKLT_CSMRED_6.2_ZIP_EU_MobWB_WKLT.zip to install Studio into Eclipse Luna.
Is there a way to install Studio offline where the studio zip contains all of the required software.

The error I am getting is:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730)
  Missing requirement: Model Plug-in 8.0.0.v20140612_1534 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.model 8.0.0.v20140612_1534) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.type.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Web Page Generation Core Plugin 7.2.500.v20140612_1534 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core 7.2.500.v20140612_1534)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.model [8.0.0,9.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Mobile Application Tools 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730 (com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730)
    To: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core [6.2.0.00-20140613-0730]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730)
    To: com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 6.2.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Core 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730 (com.ibm.imp.worklight.core 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.webpage.core [7.2.0,8.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 6.2.0.00-20140613-0730)
    To: com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 6.2.0
```

Comment: If my answer helped you solve this issue, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to install it offline Follow these steps:

1- Download these components

a. Eclipse: Choose what fits for your operating system (32 vs 64).

b. Eclipse Plugins:

```
i. Eclipse modeling - emf model transaction

ii. Eclipse modeling - emf Validation Framework

iii. GMF Runtime

iv. Worklight/Mobile First Studio plugin

v. Android Developer Tools for Eclipse
```

c. Android SDK

d. JDK 7 (install JDK 64 only on 64 OS and JDK 32 only on 32 OS don’t mix JDK        32 on OS 64 or Eclipse won’t start) Then in Java SE Development Kit 7u80 click Accept License Agreement And choose the JDK appropriate to your OS.

2- Install them in the following order:

a. Install JDK.

b. Extract Eclipse IDE.

c. Install these plugins using Help -> install new software -> archive (Don’t restart).

```
i.  From previous point No. 1-b ( i- ii- v).
```

d. Shutdown Eclipse.

e. Extract the contents of No. 1 -b (iii) directly into Eclipse (extract all in the folder that contains Eclipse IDE).

f. Start Eclipse.

g. Install WorkLight/MobileFirst Studio plugin 1-b(iv).

For download links review the following document.

https://doc.co/RjbNmx

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The Worklight installation requires Internet connection at this time.

You are encouraged, though, to submit a feature request to address this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Best workaround is to install Eclipse and Worklight Studio only, zip it and then use this zip as the base of any future installations...